# Select Columns Conditionally in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to select every column that its name does not contain Id

This is what I have tried:

```
Select *
From Table_Name
Where Column_Name Like '%Id%'
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Show us some sample data, and which rows you want to select (and which ones not)

Comment: I think he's trying to get the name of the columns, not the data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. Assume table as column id,value1,value2. You need to select column name having name like `value`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value1] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [value2] [varchar](4) NULL)


GO

create table  #tblcols (colname varchar(100))

insert into #tblcols
select Column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tbl1'

delete from #tblcols where colname not like '%val%'
select * from #tblcols

declare @sql nvarchar(500)


SELECT @sql = COALESCE(@sql + ', ', ' ') +  colname FROM #tblcols


 set @sql = 'select ' + @sql + ' from tbl1'
 select @sql

 exec sp_executesql  @sql

 drop table  #tblcols
```

Then, using dynamic SQL create sql statement like `select value1,value2 from tbl`. And use `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL` to get result.

Comment: Thank you,
it helped so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA for this.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Name Of Your Table, As A String'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%Id%'
```

[More on INFORMATION_SCHEMA from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
select * from sys.columns where
name NOT like '%ID%'
```

[sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176106.aspx)

or

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME NOT   like '%ID%'
```

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)